# Redirect .htm to .html - IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

We've rebuilt our Website and our extensions will be `.html`. Currently, they are `.htm`. When a user visits our site from a bookmarked page for example that's `.htm`, I want it to redirect to the `.html` version.

I have looked through stackoverflow to see if there is already a Q&A on this. Most are Apache - .htaccess related. I'm using IIS. The closest answer I could find on stackoverflow is this one: [IIS url rewrite rewriting all .asp to .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790880/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-all-asp-to-html)

I tried following the advice in that post, but it's not working. The webpage tells me `This webpage has a redirect loop.` and `Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

I'm in the URL Rewrite module in IIS. I create a new "blank rule" for inbound rules. Here are the settings I'm using as advised by that stackoverflow post: (BTW, I would have posted this in that thread, but it's over 3 years old, so I wasn't sure if that was advised)

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern

Using: Regular Expressions

Pattern: `(.*).htm(.*)`

Ignore Case is checked.

Conditions: Local Grouping: Match All

I Added a condition...

Condition Method: `{REQUEST_METHOD}`

Check if input string: Matches the Pattern

Pattern: `^GET$`

Ignore Case is checked

Action type: Redirect

Redirect URL: `{R:1}.html{R:2}`

Append Query String is checked

Redirect type: Permanent (301)

I'm doing a 301 because I want the search engines to know our URL extensions have changed.  Our URLs are exactly the same. The only difference is they're going to be `.html` instead of `.htm`. So... `something/something.htm` is `something/something.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule should be as simple as:

```
<rule name="htm to html" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.+).htm$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

Or in the configuration screen:

[image: rule]

This rule will redirect any url ending with `.htm` and containing at least one more character than `.htm` to the same url but replacing `.htm` with `.html`

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. I'm not getting any more looping errors. Many, many thanks!